# Windows command prompt set clipboard without trailing newline

Tags: clipboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need a command that sets the contents of the clipboard to whatever is piped to its input without adding a trailing newline. The following:

```
C:> *some_command* | clip.exe
```

adds a newline at the end, while:

```
C:> *some_command* | powershell.exe Set-Clipboard
```

does not seem to pass the standard input to `Set-Clipboard`. Invoking `*some_command*` via a powershell prompt is not an option. How can I do what I need?

*Background:* I am using WSL and I want to be able to copy/paste to the system clipboard from vim, tmux, etc. My current workaround uses `clip.exe` which adds a newline to whatever I yank. For example, in `.vimrc` I [have](https://superuser.com/a/1567222/474627):

```
let g:copy = 'clip.exe'
let g:paste = 'powershell.exe Get-Clipboard -Raw'
augroup myYank
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.operator == 'y' | call system(g:copy, @") | let g:lastyank='y' | else | let g:lastyank='' | endif
  "autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.operator ==# 'y' | call system(g:copy, @") | endif
  "autocmd TextYankPost * call system(g:copy, @")
augroup END
function! Paste(mode)
  if g:lastyank == 'y'
    let @" = system(g:paste)
  endif
  return a:mode
endfunction
map <expr> p Paste('p')
map <expr> P Paste('P')
" map Ctrl-c and Ctrl-x as expected
func! GetSelectedText()
  normal gv"xy
  let result = getreg("x")
  return result
endfunc
noremap <C-c> :call system(g:copy, GetSelectedText())<CR>
noremap <C-x> :call system(g:copy, GetSelectedText())<CR>gvx
```

Answer (score 0):

output your command in a variable then use `$var.trim() | Set-Clipboard`, but the best would be to generate the proper output first rather than correcting it down the line so maybe the string builder could help you.

`$SB = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::New()`

Then you can try this depending on the result you want, the string builder will store everything in it's corresponding variable.

`$SB.Append($Text)`

`$SB.AppendLine($Text)`

Then finally

`$SB | SCB`

Sometime also

`Out-String -NoNewLine`

can help but certain commands will generate blank lines at the end by default so trimming can come in handy sometimes.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.